# asp button click event

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using C#.net for creating an aspx page (Visual Studio 2010).
I have copied most of the template code from online ( HTML ) but when I drop a button of asp and double click it, it doesn't redirect to the code behind page but, instead creates "onclick=btnSubmit_Click" event in the source code.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Height="30px" 
Width="100px" **onclick="btnSubmit_Click"** />
```

Ideally it should go to the code behind page and allow event handling stuffs, I have no idea why this is happening.

My question is:
1. What do I do in order to get redirected like normal asp pages in Visual Studio
2. If possible, can someone explain what am I doing wrong here?

**I did get a way around it by using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    txtName.Text="btn submit clicked"
End Sub
```

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

please make sure that your `<%Page` directive has mentioned **CodeBehind** file.

i.e

something like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/example.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Example.default" %>
```

this will be on the top of your aspx page

Comment: Its not there in mine, I probaby ended up removing it when I pasted the HTML code. Now when I am doing <b><%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="contact" %></b> it shows syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below methods.

**Method 1:**

Based on what I found here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1229894.aspx/1

1. Right click on your solution explorer.
2. Add New Item -> Class File.
3. Name the file as the name of your aspx eg: Default.aspx.cs
4. When it asks you the file should be in app_code click "no".
5. In your aspx in page attribute add

   AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default"

   **<%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>**
6. Similarly in your class file that you just added remove everything. Your class should look like this:

   public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

   ```
   }
   ```

   }

**Method 2:** while adding new page please make sure the place code in separate file box is checked

[image]

Comment: Now that I have added the statement to the file, it shows " 'Class' statement must end with a matching 'End Class' "

Comment: Please provide your aspx page and C# class full code.

Comment: I am trying to put the code(by editing my question), but its automatically rendering the html code(the javascript ones are fine). Dunno how to post it here. Sorry but I am new to stack overflow. Please lemme know how I can share the entire code without rendering it.